# Can Cloud Functions for Firebase be set up to work with Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to set up a cloud function to use in my Realtime Database. I went to the [setup page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) and the instructions do not appear to be for Firebase for Unity. Is it not possible to use cloud functions with Unity or am I reading the instructions wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Functions for Firebase operates completely independently of any client SDK.  It facilitates server-side development, not client-side.  It's not at all opinionated about what platform(s) your app is built on.

Comment: There are special client sdks for firebase cloud functions, for web, android, ios. Apparently, not for Unity yet, so you have to do a www url call in unity to call a cloud function.